# Logic Level Converter not converting low logic level as expected?

Tags: logic-level

I'm trying to convert 1.5V logic levels from a caliper data port to 3.3v to be able to read it with a microcontroller, using one of the [sparkfun logic level converters](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009). The product page mentions it can be used for 1.8V logic levels, so I was hoping 1.5V would work as well.

When I look at the waveform generated on the HV side, the high logic level is at the expected voltage, but the low logic level is much higher than expected, and I'm not sure why.

Interestingly, if I connect the LV side directly to the ground and 1.5V from the caliper's data port, the HV side shows 0V and 3.3V as expected

I have it hooked up like so. Note: the probe was actually connected to the CLK pin on both sides (LV2/HV2), not the data pin as shown. Although I got similar results when looking at the data signal.

[image]

And here are the traces from the LV side and the HV side.

(LV)
[image]
(HV)
[image]

I eventually got it working by using a rail-to-rail opamp instead, since I only need unidirectional conversion, but I'd like to understand why I was seeing unexpected results with this. And why connecting the LV side directly to ground produced different results than the low logic level from the clock/data pins.

My best guess is that maybe the clock/data pins from the caliper are unable to sink much current when in a low logic level state?

Comment: It is not clear where power for low voltage side coming from. The 1.5V on a "caliper" looks like power input, not output. Any datasheet?

Comment: The caliper is normally powered from a little button cell. As far as I can tell, the ground and voltage pin on the data port are directly connected to the battery. So you can also remove the battery and power the caliper with an external 1.5V source via the data port. I actually tried both configurations, with the same result.

Comment: Are HV1 and HV2 connected to MCU as well? Is this I2C or MISO-only SPI?

Comment: No. They were disconnected from anything other than the probe. Eventually I would connect them to the MCU of course. I didn't get that far, because the waveform wasn't what I was expecting.

Comment: Well, I can't say without datasheet, but if these are I2C or SPI then they need clock signal to work. Without it what you see could be some weak signal bleeding to data pin, not strong enough to open MOSFET properly

Comment: Yeah, there are no datasheets for these, just random posts on the internet from people who have reversed engineered them. There seems to be a number of different variations as well. The caliper generates its own clock and data waveforms, and doesn't require any input. It's not exactly I2C or SPI as far as I can tell. It just sends 24 bits  with a typical clock+data signal every 100ms or so.

Comment: The first 20 bits seem to be a fixed point number, scaled by the minimum resolution of the caliper, with the final 4 bits being various status bits (negative/positive, whether the caliper is in in or mm mode, etc.)

Comment: Well, if this part of yours produces its own clock then there is no telling what output signals it uses. It's "0" output could be not low enough to fully close the FET. I can't tell from the scope what it is.

Comment: The low logic level is approximately the same voltage level as the ground level on the port. the little yellow "1" arrow on the left of the LV image shows the ground level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If level converter works when you directly connect LV input to GND or 1.5V and does not work from DATA/CLK pins then it means logic levels on those outputs do not have enough swing to switch the FET. Or maybe do not have enough sink capability.

One possible workaround is to reduce pull-up strength on that adapter board from 10K to 22K or more (on LV side only).

However more reliable solution would be to use different level shifter, something that does not depend on Vgs of the MOSFET and has high input impedance. Like [PCA9306](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11955) for example.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! It would be interesting to try to reduce the pull up strength to see if that has an effect. I guess I could bridge data to the 1.5V pin with another resistor, which should be in parallel with the existing pull-up resistor and should reduce the overall resistance. As mentioned in the post, I did eventually get it working with an opamp instead, so this is mostly just for my own edification :)

Comment: The goal is to **increase** resistance (= reduce pull-up _strength_), not reduce it. Also, OP-amp sounds like huge overkill for this application, simple transistor buffer would be sufficient

Comment: ahhh, that makes sense, thanks!  And yeah, I'm sure it is. but I happened to have some handy, so.. :). Besides, the specific one I'm using is only $.33 each, so it's not exactly breaking the bank for a one-off project.

Comment: No problem. If you feel like it, post the results of the experiment. By the way, thinking on how this adapter operates, you might need to increase resistance on HV side as well. Not only output pin should be able to pull 1.5V to the ground, but when FET opens it also connects 3.3V pull-up resistor to it, so pin has to sink that as well.

Comment: I took a break from this project for a while, but just took it back up. I revisited this, desoldered the pull up resistor on the HV side and replaced it with a 22k pull up, which did improve things, but not quite enough. I replaced it with a 100k pull up and the swing was much wider, nearly rail to rail. The low voltage level was at around .1V or so.

Comment: Looks like your solution with opamp was the best and simplest, after all.

Comment: Hmm? Decreasing the pull-up strength as you had suggested worked. I just had to decrease it a bit more than suggested. The slew rate suffered with the higher pull-up resistance of course, but it's a slow enough signal that it's still acceptable.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess I misunderstood "not quite enough" as final result. Well, as long as MCU understands it, it's all good. Nice job!